# What does the Statue of Extra Liberty represent?

Tags: mythology, design, maniac

In [this interview](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/maniac-statue-extra-liberty-ad-buddy-explained-1146114) with show runner Patrick Somerville, we have:

> In one standout absurdist moment in this wonky New York, a tour guide points out a winged "Statue of Extra Liberty" across the water (seen above). "New York needed more liberty!" Somerville joked, before offering a clarification. "I saw some people writing about it, and that is actually not the harbor. The camera is pointing north in that shot, so in the Maniac world, the Statue of Liberty still exists, and the Statue of Extra Liberty also exists. Someone decided that we needed another one."

[image]

Who or what exactly is this winged lightning-wielding male Statue of Extra Liberty intended to be based on or represent?

Comment: That's a very good question. The body is clearly the depiction of a (winged) angel holding a thunderbolt (reminscent of Zeus) and holding an apple. Get it? A **big apple**.

Comment: @Valorum:   Oh, I thought it was just a knife.   I guess you're right.   That's at least part of an answer....

Comment: @Valorum:   Are you really sure it's an apple?

Comment: There's a better zoom here; https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJjDN.png. I was trying to puzzle out what he was holding until I saw the close-up. Then I was like "why is he holding a ball? Why is he holding an apple? Oh yeah. Because it's New York and this is literally the lamest reference imaginable"

Comment: Mmm be careful trying to read too much into the design. The actual tatie of Liberty was originally designed wearing a Phrygian cap, for example. But that symbolism was lost. Were you to look at her and not know our history, you would wonder why she’s holding a tablet, etc.

Comment: @Broklynite:   I don't understand the point.  Yes, I might wonder why she carries a tablet, and I would post somewhere to get an answer as to the symbolism.   Why would you advise not reading too much into it?   Someone had to decide the appearance of the SoEL and presumably they put some thought into it.   Or if not, it's still an answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I’m not explaining myself well. My point is more that it may be an assemblage of different symbols which to our minds might not add up to a unifying symbol of extra liberty but would to the people of that world. Make more sense? Apologies if more autocorrect spellings creep in unnoticed.

Comment: @Broklynite:   Sure.   It might.   The answer could equally well be that it's an assembly of components into something new.   Or not.   I believe that's your point.   Who knows?   Answer: whoever answers the question does.    Maybe the designer just thought "Hmmm, what are a bunch of pseudo-mythologically inspired symbols I can assemble together?  Wings, a lightning bolt, and an apple.   Job well done!"   Or maybe it wasn't so arbitrary.  Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: I don't know if it is meant to be anyone specifically, but I think it relates to Owen and Hawk metaphor/memory - there is a theme of escapism vs doing what is right.

Comment: It also kind of reminds me of "stabbing fear" something like The Heart of Darkness, but I'm just speculating.